# Return Vue Variable or Vue Component to Laravel Blade

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuetify.js

```
$outputs = '';

foreach ($results->innovators as $innovator) {
    $outputs .= '<v-img height="120" width="125" src="/storage/' . $innovator->logo . '"></v-img>';
}

return $outputs;
```

I am returning the Whole data its just a dummy lines.I have to utilize the vue variable in laravel blade ,besidse vue/vuetify variable everything of HTML etc are working fine .Can I use the Vue by sending this at blade front end.

Comment: You most certainly can. A blade view is just a rendered html page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible.

Vue is using virtual DOM and it should be ready to convert Real DOM with render So I don't think it's possible.

Even though it works in such way but it's not good practice because we can use REST API for your function.

I do not recommend to use Vue with PHP although it's not work.. There is already blade template to use easily in Laravel.